# How do I integrate a Bootstrap template in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, templates, web, intellij-idea

I downloaded this bootstrap template from here https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/ and I have try to integrate in Intellij Idea.

I put the folders: css, img, js, scss, vendor in the static folder from Idea and index in templates folder form Idea.

```
 I modify everywhere in index with :  href="../static/.. 
 for example : <link href="../static/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

What to do to work? :)

Comment: What are you trying to integrate it into, and what exactly does not work?

Comment: When I try to access the index.html,  appear only the HTML simple, without bootstrap or icons or anything. He doesn't seem to see the css, img, scss, vendor..

Comment: What type of project do you have, and where is your index.html located?

Comment: I have a spring project. And my index.html is in templates

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me following your steps and opening the HTML page with 'Open in browser' option of the IDE.

Are all paths correctly resolved in the editor?

Does your project's structure is the same as in the screenshot?
[image]